# How to generate spring cloud feign client using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

Tags: spring-cloud, swagger-codegen, spring-cloud-feign

I want to generate my feign client code using swagger-codegen, but I cannot find the docs which can lead me to do it.

I have a microservice using spring cloud, several api-services using spring-cloud-feign interfaces to request the data.I wish that i can generate the feign client code.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>http://localhost:9141/v2/api-docs?group=building-service-api</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</output>
                            <library>feign</library>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

language/library set to 'java/feign', there are only models without feign client;

language set to 'spring', 'feign' is unsupported library.

I am confused how to generate all my code? There seems to be almost no guideline or doc or demo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `spring-cloud-starter-feign` dependency in your pom.xml and:

```
<configuration>
    <language>spring</language>
    <library>spring-cloud</library>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can't make it work. I get the following when `mvn compile`:
`io.swagger.codegen.v3:swagger-codegen-maven-plugin:3.0.2:generate failed: Unknown library: spring-cloud
[ERROR] Available libraries:
[ERROR]   spring-boot
[ERROR]   spring-mvc`. Any suggestion? I tried adding spring-cloud-starter-feign but didn't work.

Comment: @GerardBosch I am having the same problem. Have you, by any chance, fixed it somehow?

Comment: @MihaiP. I changed the approach while I started playing with and understood what I needed. (1) I am not generating Feign clients as in my case they only consist in one annotation `@FeignClient`, so I can't see the necessity. (2) I am using the updated `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` instead (you can check its github) with `<generatorName>spring</generatorName>`and `<library>spring-cloud</library>`, but I am only generating models (OAS schemas) and spring-mvc interfaces as I generate contracts as JARs. I add the required Spring dependencies as `provided` just to compile generated contract lib.

Comment: Just a note that the latest dependency is renamed to `spring-cloud-starter-openfeign`. The `spring-cloud-starter-feign` is outdated