# How to use a Swagger generated client (Feign)

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-codegen, feign

After generating a client library as explained on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019180/how-to-generate-spring-cloud-feign-client-using-swagger-codegen-maven-plugin)
I'm trying to use this library in my consumer, I added the dependency and added `@EnableFeignClients` annotation on my main class.
However, when starting the app, Spring complains that there is an unsatisfied dependency, the generated interface from the library having the annotation `@FeignClient` doesn't seem to be scanned or instantiated.
Is there any specific configuration to do when including such a generated swagger client lib ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am struggling with the same problem for quite some time, I would like to share what I've to get this working temporarily. By default swagger will use the legacy feign client instead of the new openfeign, so you have to enable the config option `generateForOpenFeign` directly. Also if you want to use java8, to avoid the default interfaces (which do nothing) being generated, you have set the config option `defaultInterfaces` to false.

Here is how my `swagger_config.json` looks like:

```
{
"artifactId": "example-sdk",
"artifactVersion": "1.0.0",
"groupId": "com.example",
"apiPackage": "com.example.api",
"modelPackage": "com.example.model",
"configPackage": "com.example.configuration",
"generateForOpenFeign": true,
"java8": true,
"defaultInterfaces": false
}
```

After the source files are generating, I have to update the dependencies of `spring-cloud` and `spring-boot-starter` in the `pom.xml` to make de source code compilable.

Here is what I have updated:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

To use the generated feign clients, I have to put
`@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.example.api"})` in the main class of my client application.
I know this is not the best solution, if someone has better idea, please advise.